# Run a single test with multiple configs in parallel using pytest

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I have to run the same test against different hosts in parallel. Currently, i'm making a bunchof pytest.main() calls. But this is not run in parallel and results are not aggregated. This is the content of runtest.py:

```
pytest.main('--conf=c1.txt')
pytest.main('--conf=c2.txt')
pytest.main('--conf=c3.txt')
```

I have just one test_host.py which looks something like:

```
test_pinghost(conf):
    # pings a host in config
```

Is there a way to run this in parallel  and aggregate results?
PS:the config filejust contains the host IP

Comment: From what I know about python, is that even with the use of threads there is one global lock. So at any given time only one thread will be executing, which makes true parallel processing tricky...

Comment: Agree. But is there a way to run `test_pinghost` with different configs and aggregate the test results? One way would be parameterized tests but I simply want to use the runner to do this work.

Answer (score 6):

Please use http://pytest.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.3/xdist.html, it enables pytest to run tests across multiple processes/machines